# Smarty 3.1.30, php 7.0.26 Compatibility issues?

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I have used smarty with php5.x for years. I recently upgraded my dev box to php7.2 and smarty to php 3.1.30. Works great.

Our production server was just upgraded to php 7.0.26. My code on my local machine and the production server is nearly identical (config file differences, for example.) Unfortunately, on that server `$smarty->fetch(<filename>);` returns an empty string.

Does anyone know if there is compatibility issues between smarty 3.1.30 and php 7.0.26? Have you ever encountered `fetch()` returning an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the server did not allocate enough memory to PHP processes. Not sure why, but it would die silently during Smarty fetch processing and return an empty string - no errors in log files, etc. Once I increased allowable memory allocation it was fine. Wanted to post an answer to how I fixed in case anyone out there is looking.